# beforFilter in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp

What is the best way to do and equivalent to CakePHP's beforeFilter() in codeIgniter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sounds like [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) might be what you're after

**CakePHP**
*beforeFilter()*

This function is executed before every action in the controller. It's a handy place to check for an active session or inspect user permissions.or inspect user permissions.

**CodeIgniter**
*pre controller*

Called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done.

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MyClass',
                                'function' => 'Myfunction',
                                'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
                                );
```

maybe?

Comment: in application/config/config.php ensure you have $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;